# View traffic logs and metrics for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Does anybody know where and if you can view Google Cloud Storage traffic metrics. I can find the storage used just fine but i cannot find the metrics related to EGRESS and INGRESS traffic.